# String Format returns unexpected result

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I'm just wondering why this code

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"); and String.Format("{0: MM/dd/yyyy}", DateTime.Now);
```

both returns 03 31 2016 instead of 03/31/2016.

Comment: What are your CultureInfo settings for _CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.DateSeparator_

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`/` is a [format specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx#dateSeparator) which is transformed to your localized date separator. Either wrap it in apostrophes or use the overload with `DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo`.

```
Console.WriteLine( DateTime.Now.ToString("MM'/'dd'/'yyyy") );  
Console.WriteLine( DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy", DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo) );
```

or with `String.Format`:

```
Console.WriteLine( String.Format("{0:MM'/'dd'/'yyyy}", DateTime.Now) );
Console.WriteLine( String.Format(DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo, "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", DateTime.Now) );
```

You can also use `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` instead of `DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo`.

Answer (score 0):

Tim's answer is awesome.  You could also use c# v6 string interpolation:

```
var x = DateTime.Now.ToString($"MM/dd/yyyy");
var y = $"{DateTime.Now: MM/dd/yyyy}";
```